# What debugger can be used with D 2.0 on windows and how do I use it?

Tags: debugging, d

I have been playing around with D 2.0 a bit today mostly because of the "The Case for D" in DDJ.

I have downloaded D 2.0 for windows but have not figured out how to step through a running program in the debugger.

I tried to get the shipped copy of windbg.exe to work but it is crashing on me all the time and does not seem to see the source code.

Comment: I got the following working on Windows:
Eclipse with Descent for IDE 
http://www.dsource.org/projects/descent
After install I set up rebuild for compilation
http://www.dsource.org/projects/descent/wiki/CompilingPrograms
And this is how to set up the debugger
http://www.dsource.org/projects/descent/wiki/DebuggingPrograms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a Windows debugger called Mago: http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/gfp48/mago_a_windows_debugger_for_the_d_programming/

Answer (score 6):

There is a Windows debugger written specifically for D:

http://ddbg.mainia.de/

Answer (score 6):

Debugging in Visual Studio 2008 Express works like a charm for me with this tool:
http://www.dsource.org/projects/cv2pdb

You can also use windbg 4 or msvc 6, but then you won't see the values of the special D types (like dynamic arrays and hashes) easily.

Answer (score 4):

Have you seen [Visual D](http://www.dsource.org/projects/visuald)?

> Visual D is a Visual Studio package providing both project management and language services. It works with Visual Studio 2005, 2008 and 2010 as well as the free Visual Studio Shells.

It's open source (The Artistic License 2.0), written in D itself and provides both a development and a debugging experience, through integration with the aforementioned `cv2pdb`.